# My code seems to have a syntax error in finding the maximum number

Tags: c++, max

What is wrong with my code?
It has to find the maximum between `n` numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];
    while(i < n)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        i++;
    }
    i=1;
    while(i <= (n + 1))
    {
        if (a[i] > a[0])
        {
            a[0] = a[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << a[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If your code has a syntax error, the compiler should tell you where. Why didn't you post it?

Comment: Here is a syntax error, virtual length arrays (VLA), `int a[n];`.  The standard C++ language does not support them.  Use `std::vector` it can grow dynamically.

Comment: `int a[n];` is not standard c++. Some compilers support it [as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). You should use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Also, do not abuse the placement of curly braces like that. Making your code look like Python doesn't make it more readable. In fact it does the opposite in C++. Skilled C++ programmer will look for the closing **curly brace** along with the indentation to determine scope. You just made it 10 times harder.

Comment: how should I use std::vector?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is meant to be a learning thing for you so I don't want to do your code for you.  That being said I would look at `while(i <= (n + 1))`.  You are stepping outside of the bounds of your array.